# Introducing old cat to new kitten

Tags: cats, introducing-pets

Just got a female kitten and my fixed senior boy kitty isn’t too happy. I bought a cat pheromone plug. Gonna try it tonight but still keep them seperate. Any suggestions on other products that may help?